# sql - comparing substrings instead of entire string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select substring(datapath,1,5), COUNT(substring(datapath,1,5)) from batchinfo
where datapath like '%thc%'
group by datapath
having COUNT(substring(datapath,1,5))>1
```

i am trying to count how many of each substrings there are in the table and for some reason it counts the ENTIRE string. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to GROUP BY the substring you're trying to count instead of the full datapath. There's also no need to repeat the substring function on the count.

```
select substring(datapath,1,5), COUNT(*) 
    from batchinfo
    where datapath like '%thc%'
    group by substring(datapath,1,5)
    having COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select d, count(*)
from
(
    select substring(datapath,1,5) d from batchinfo
    where datapath like '%thc%'
)
group by d
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I like this because you're not repeating the substring